# How do I convert this code from Firebase Firestore v8 to Firebase Firestore v9 Modular in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm having trouble changing this code from firebase v8 to the modular version of firebase v9 in reactjs.

```
const uploadFirestore = useCallback(async() => {
  await db.collection('users').doc(res.user.uid).collection('tareas').add({
    name: 'Test Task',
    fecha: Date.now()
  })
})
```

And i want to convert it to firebase 9 modular, also pass the userUid in the collections.

I was trying making it this way:

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import { db } from "./firebase"
import { collection, doc, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

function App(props) {
  const uploadFirestore = useCallback(async() => {
    await addDoc(doc(db, 'users', props.user.uid, 'tareas'), {
      name: 'Test Task',
      fecha: Date.now()
    })
  })
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={uploadFirestore}>
        Upload
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is my firebase.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';


const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
    hidden api uwu
  });


const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

export { db }
```

But it throws a:

> TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function

Any help?

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you tried that doesn't work the way you expect along with any errors.  Start with the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) which shows examples to work from.

Comment: @DougStevenson i update the question, check it out uwu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
addDoc(doc(db, 'users', props.user.uid, 'tareas'), ...
```

You're trying to add a document to a document, which has two problems:

1. Documents can only be added to a collection, not to other documents.
2. You're passing a path to a collection (`tareas`) to the call to `doc`.

What you want here is:

```
addDoc(collection(db, 'users', props.user.uid, 'tareas'), ...
```